# XSL + XPath to access another element in another branch

Tags: xslt

Good Day,

I need to return a value in an element that is not part of a current process branch.
In other words it is a zigzag away from my current position.

I'm currently located in the dark blue element, and need to return a value in the light blue element.
As below;

[XSD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQErQ.png)

My code is as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$HDRLVL/ITEMLEVEL/ORDITMINF">
          <xsl:call-template name="Lines"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

 <xsl:template xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" name="Lines">
        <LINE>  
          <MainRef>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$MainVessel = 'BlueWhale'">
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ROUTES/REF[@ADDTYP='CA' and CDE='AFA']/VAL"/>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </MainRef>    
        </LINE>
  </xsl:template>
```

So you can see that I am trying to access an element which occurs outside of the current looping block.
I have tried various methods such as '..', 'ancestor' etc, but am not able to return a single value in the light blue block.

Please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the schema, the ROUTES element is not in the same axis as ORDITMINF.

So you could select the element you want using an absolute path, as in:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//SHPLVL/SPHINF/SEA/ROUTES/REF[@ADDTYP='CA' and CDE='AFA']/VAL"/>
```